# In which field is the numeric (byte) ip addressed stored?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

I am wondering in which field is the numeric 32 bit representation of the ip address stored in.

you have the following structures from the API:

```
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t s_addr;
}

struct sockaddr_in {
    ...
    ...
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
    ...
}
```

And I have the following code:

```
 struct addrinfo addrCriteria;
  memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria));
  addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_INET;
  addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

  struct addrinfo *addrList;

  int rtnVal = getaddrinfo(serverIP, portNumber, &addrCriteria, &addrList);
  if (rtnVal != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo() failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }
```

**`numericAddress = &((struct sockaddr_in *) addrList->ai_addr)->sin_addr;`**

```
  addrList->sin_port = htons(servPort);
```

Please look at the line in bold. I would like to save the bit representation of the ip address in the variable named numericAddress.

numericAddress is initialized as `void *numericAddress;`

My question is, do I need to access the variable s_addr, which is a field in the in_addr struct, or is it sufficient to use sin_addr to access the bit value?

Comment: There is no bold line... Anyway, use an `uint32_t` for a binary (numeric) IPv4-address.

Comment: ok so how do I access that field? should I do: numericAddress = &((struct sockaddr_in *) addrList->ai_addr)->sin_addr->s_addr?

Comment: Yes, typecasting `addrList->ai_addr` to `sockaddr_in*` (make sure `addrList->ai_family` is `AF_INET` first) to access its `sin_addr.s_addr` field is the correct thing to do.  But why are you saving a **pointer** to the field instead of saving the **value** of the field? Once you call `freeaddrinfo(addrList)`, your pointer won't be valid anymore.